# delete line, of a .csv, when certain column has no value python

Tags: python, csv, row, erase

I have a .csv file and I am trying to erase some rows/lines that have no usable information. I want to delete lines that do not have a value in a certain column. I am kinda new to programming and I could not find a way to do this. Is this possible?

I tried to delete a line if it did not have a certain number in it but that did not work as wel.

```
f = open('C:myfile.csv', 'rb')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

filename = 'myfile.csv'

f = open(filename, 'wb')
for line in lines:
    if line != "1":
        f.write(line)

f.close()
```

here are some sample rows:

```
0,593   0,250984    -20,523384  -25,406271
0,594   0,250984        
0,595   0,250984        
0,596   0,250984        
0,597   0,250984    -15,793088  -21,286336
0,598   0,250984        
0,599   0,908811        
0,6     0,893612        
0,601   0,784814    -12,130922  -11,825742
0,602   0,909238        
0,603   0,25309     
0,604   0,38435     
0,605   0,602954    -8,316167   -3,43328
0,606   0,642628        
0,607   0,39201     
0,608   0,384289        
0,609   0,251656    -11,825742  -5,874723
```

So I want to delete the rows when there is no number in the third and fourth column.

Comment: Have you tried coding this yet? Can you share your code and explain what is currently not working out for you?

Comment: can you show us some sample rows? you tagged your question with python, any sample python code and/or research?

Comment: Please don't put code in comments — edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) library to help you do this. Your data appears to be tab delimited, as such the following script should work:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter = '\t')

    for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter = '\t'):
        if len(row[2]) and len(row[3]):
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving you an `output.csv` file containing:

```
0,593   0,250984    -20,523384  -25,406271
0,597   0,250984    -15,793088  -21,286336
0,601   0,784814    -12,130922  -11,825742
0,605   0,602954    -8,316167   -3,43328
0,609   0,251656    -11,825742  -5,874723
```

Note, each of your rows appears to have 4 columns (your data has tabs for these missing entries), because of this, it is not enough to simply test the length is `4`. You need to test the contents of the two cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

fn_in = 'test.csv'
fn_out = 'outfile.csv'

with open(fn_in, 'r') as inp, open(fn_out, 'w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if len(row)==4:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Please explain your code to make your answer more helpful for others.